# How to have linux kernel trace printed to console

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, tracepoint

I am debugging an problem wherein sometimes, `reboot` command just does not boot.
Very similar to https://e2e.ti.com/support/processors-group/processors/f/processors-forum/1086480/am3352-linux-reboot-command-hangs-for-10-minutes-while-booting-down-then-succeeds but not the same.

Can "tracefs" be used for it ? I ask this because in all examples I have seen the trace-buffer is stored in `/sys/kernel/tracing/trace`, and then later this file is dumped.

Since the issue is in the reboot sequence, I will not have the option to dump this.

Is there a way that I can have the trace-buffer to be directly printed to console ?

I looked at `tp_printk` kernel cmdline option.  However when I enable the "function_graph" I still see the output in the trace file but not console.

Could you let me know the parameters that need to be set to have the tracing subsystem print the trace to console.

Thanks

Comment: set the loglevel and console on the kernel command line https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.19-rc8/source/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt#L698

Comment: @stark tracefs does not print to dmesg, so that doesn't help OP

Comment: Yes, there is a specific command line for that (I don't remember by heart), just read documentation, it's all written there.